# Point-plot with small lines as markers - how to obtain thin but extended lines?

Tags: r, plot, markers

I'd like to plot several sequences of numbers as a point plot, but with markers being lines instead of points. One way is by using `pch='-'`:

```
## example 10 sequences, each with 15 values
data <- t(sapply(1:15, function(x){rnorm(n=10, mean=x)}))

matplot(x=1:15, y=data, type='p', pch='-', cex=1, col='black')
```

The result:
[image: plot with cex=1]

is fine, except that I'd like the lines to be have a larger horizontal extension – let's say "wider lines". Using a string of hyphens, `pch='----'`, doesn't produce wider lines.

I can fix their width with a different `cex`:

```
matplot(x=1:15, y=data, type='p', pch='-', cex=5, col='black')
```

and the result:
[image: plot with cex=5]

has the width I'd like, but now the lines are too thick.

I wonder if there's a way to separately choose the magnification of the markers in the x and y directions, or to obtain the desired result in a different way.

#### Edit:

One possible solution is to put several copies of the same data side by side, with small x-increments:

```
matplot(x=1:15, y=data, type='p', pch='-', cex=1, col='black')
for(dx in seq(-0.3, 0.3, by=0.1)){
    matpoints(x=(1:15)+dx, y=data, type='p', pch='-', cex=1, col='black')
}
```

The result is more or less as I'd like it:
[image: sequence of plots]

but I wonder if there's a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Two quick thoughts.

1. Find a font with a really long "dash" or "Underline" character and use that.
2. This will be slow, but replace every ordered pair {x,y} in your dataset with two points {x-k,y},{x+k,y} and plot lines between each pair separately.

Comment: Thank you, I'll explore both! Another way is to plot the data several times, but with their x-values differing by small amounts. That way their lines will add up together. But I'd like to find some plainer solution...